# Java SWT - shell's titlebar disappear when using SWT.V_SCROLL on shell

Tags: java, shell, scroll, swt, titlebar

Well, I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but when I use SWT.V_SCROLL on shell, its titlebar disappears. In addition, shell window cannot be resized or moved. I'm using Windows 8.1, Eclipse 4.4 and SWT 4.4 (all are x64 versions).

```
    final private static Shell shell = new Shell(SWT.V_SCROLL);

    //shell init
    shell.setSize(850, 900);
    shell.setLocation(200, 10);
    Rectangle shellSize = shell.getBounds();
    shell.setMinimumSize(shellSize.width, shellSize.height);

    FormLayout layout_shell = new FormLayout();
    shell.setLayout(layout_shell);
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: http://snag.gy/OzfNv.jpg]

When used 'clean' shell:

```
    final private static Shell shell = new Shell();
```

[image: http://snag.gy/mEuK2.jpg]

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `new Shell(SWT.V_SCROLL)`, the generated shell will only be able to scroll and won't have any decorations and/or resize/move functionality. The default constructor (without parameter) on the other hand internally calls other constructors and sets the style to `SHELL_TRIM`.

If you want your application to be scrollable, add a `ScrolledComposite` as the first child of your `Shell`.

---

Note: using `new Shell(SWT.SHELL_TRIM | SWT.V_SCROLL)` *does* show a scrollbar, but the content won't actually scroll

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that Shell cannot have so basic function, so I didn't look at Javadoc.